# Check if word exists in docx file

Tags: c#, openxml-powertools

I have this docx file loaded in my code:

```
byte[] documentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\mydocument.docx");
```

This document contains the word "foo" in either the main body, header or footer, what is the easiest way to check for the existence of the word "foo"?

Comment: I posted this with my own answer right below, which is why this is a pretty sparse question.

Comment: while SO highly encourages users to answer their question theirselves, this doesn´t mean the question may lack any relevant information. The rules for posting a question stay exactly as if you did not answer your question, so please provide **every** relevant information into your question.

Comment: I am always up for improving my own questions. Can you give me a tip on how to in this case? Posting code seems a bit useless in this case.

Comment: actually you **can** provide your attemps and how they failed. It´s a **question**, remember? So it does not need to contain the **answer**. If I remember right your question yesterday already shows some affords.

Comment: There was no code in my previous question either. But I will add some extra code to this question so it looks fancy.

Comment: It´s not about looking fancy, but about being of use to others.

Answer (score 2):

Using [OpenXML Powertools](https://github.com/EricWhiteDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools):

```
using OpenXmlPowerTools;

...

byte[] documentBytes = GetMyBytes(); // Load the docx file with File.ReadAllBytes, generate a byte array, etc
using var myStream = new MemoryStream(result, false);
using var myDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(myStream, false); // myStream can also be replaced with a path in string format

var regex = new Regex("foo");

int headerCount = OpenXmlRegex.Match(document.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts.SelectMany(x => x.GetXDocument().Descendants(W.p)), regex);
int footerCount = OpenXmlRegex.Match(document.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts.SelectMany(x => x.GetXDocument().Descendants(W.p)), regex);
int bodyCount = OpenXmlRegex.Match(document.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument().Descendants(W.p), regex);
```

The variables `headerCount`, `footerCount` and `bodyCount` represent the number of hits for your regex per part of the document. The `MainDocumentPart` property also contains properties for images, charts, themes etc.

Comment: perhaps you want to update the repository link since the repo in the link is no longer maintained. please refer to this instead https://github.com/EricWhiteDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools